# Pay to post - Membership site

Tags: forms, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Im working on a website where users create and account and then have the option to crate "ads" thru a frontend post submission form. I´ve tried different plugins and **WPUF by WeDevs** are the one I went with.
But the plugin is kind of slow and not great to be fair, so I want to try and build this by myself.

So the front-end posting is no problem. I am used to working with ACF and their  its easy to setup. The thing is that I want to charge the user a small amount to post.

**But what is the best way to do this?** I love Stripe so I think thats the way to go, but how can I set it up?

PS: If anyone got and example of a better plugin than WPUF thats great aswell. If there is any smooth way to do it without me creating it myself thats great aswell!

Comment: I think the best way is to use woocommerce and instal the Stripe plug-in.

Comment: @Johan WPUF supports Stripe payment gateway and allows the admin to accept payment using Stripe from the users. Here is the link: https://wedevs.com/docs/wp-user-frontend-pro/modules/stripe/